Join after groupby in Spark structured streaming
When I run the following code:
    Dataset<Row> aggStreamA = df
        .withWatermark("dateTime", "2 days")
        .groupBy(
            window(col("dateTime"), windowDuration, slideDuration),
            col(colA)
        )
        .agg(count("*").alias("count_a"));

    Dataset<Row> aggStreamB = df
        .withWatermark("dateTime", "2 days")
        .groupBy(
            window(col("dateTime"), windowDuration, slideDuration),
            col(colB)
        )
        .agg(count("*").alias("count_b"));

    Dataset<Row> joinedStream = aggStreamA
        .join(
            aggStreamB,
            aggStreamA.col("window.start").equalTo(aggStreamB.col("window.start"))
                .and(aggStreamA.col("window.end").equalTo(aggStreamB.col("window.end")))
                .and(aggStreamA.col(colA).equalTo(aggStreamB.col(colB)))
            ,
            "leftOuter"
        );

    StreamingQuery query = joinedStream
        .writeStream()
        .outputMode("append")
        .format("console")
        .start();

    query.awaitTermination();

I get an error:
Stream-stream LeftOuter join between two streaming DataFrame/Datasets is not supported without a watermark in the join keys, or a watermark on the nullable side and an appropriate range condition

To overcome the problem, I tried this one:
    Dataset<Row> aggStreamB = df
        .withWatermark("dateTime", "2 days")
        .groupBy(
            window(col("dateTime"), windowDuration, slideDuration),
            col(colB)
        )
        .agg(count("*").alias("count_b")).withColumn("start", col("window.start"))
        .withColumn("start", col("window.start"))
        .withWatermark("start", "0 second");

    Dataset<Row> joinedStream = aggStreamA.as("a")
        .join(
            aggStreamB.as("b"),
            aggStreamA.col("window.start").equalTo(aggStreamB.col("window.start"))
                .and(aggStreamA.col("window.end").equalTo(aggStreamB.col("window.end")))
                .and(aggStreamA.col(colA).equalTo(aggStreamB.col(colB)))
                .and(expr("a.start >= b.start and a.start <= b.start + interval 2 days"))
            ,
            "leftOuter"
        );

    StreamingQuery query = joinedStream
        .writeStream()
        .outputMode("append")
        .format("console")
        .start();

    query.awaitTermination();

But it seems that there is a problem with the second watermarks. When I run the following code:
    Dataset<Row> aggStreamA = df
        .withWatermark("dateTime", "2 days")
        .groupBy(
            window(col("dateTime"), windowDuration, slideDuration),
            col(colA)
        )
        .agg(count("*").alias("count_a"))
        .withColumn("start", col("window.start"));


    StreamingQuery query = aggStreamA
        .writeStream()
        .outputMode("append")
        .format("console")
        .start();

    query.awaitTermination();

It returns results, but the following code returns nothing:
Dataset<Row> aggStreamA = df
        .withWatermark("dateTime", "2 days")
        .groupBy(
            window(col("dateTime"), windowDuration, slideDuration),
            col(colA)
        )
        .agg(count("*").alias("count_a"))
        .withColumn("start", col("window.start"))
        .withWatermark("start", "0 second");


    StreamingQuery query = aggStreamA
        .writeStream()
        .outputMode("append")
        .format("console")
        .start();

    query.awaitTermination();
  }

Any opinions?
Is it possible to set another watermark after aggregation?
